# NRZ (de)coding with GNURadio

Tags: gnuradio

I'm receiving a digital signal that I would like to decode.

Is there a simple way (avoiding to program by myself) to get the bit stream from a NRZ square-signal using GNU Radio ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the signal is 1 sample/symbol, you can simply use the binary slicer